# How does Learning Rate affect Gradients in Back Prop

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch

I was wondering if the learning rate is set to update the weights during the backpropagation on the layers of a neural network. How and where do the weights get updated?

I can't see the connection between optimizer, learning rate, and the backpropagation function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure a fair question that comes to mind is how are the backpropagation and the optimizer related in all of this. And how are those parameters updated by the optimizer?

```
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

Indeed there doesn't seem to be any link between `optimizer` and `loss` let alone the parameters of your model.

---

- ***Optimizer***

Every tensor object has a `grad` attribute which either contains a tensor representing the gradient corresponding to it or `None` if either it doesn't require gradient computation or simply doesn't have any gradient.

To optimize parameters in PyTorch you would go about initializing an [optimizer](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html) by passing a list or iterator over those very parameters you want this optimizer to act upon:

```
mlp = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(10, 2), nn.Linear(2, 1))
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(mlp.parameters(), lr=1.0e-3)
```

*An optimizer is not tasked with computing gradients, this is performed by another system in PyTorch.*

When you call `optimizer.step()`, the optimizer will go over each provided parameter and update them based the optimizer's update rule (*i.e.* the optimizing method used) and the gradient associated with each parameter (namely the [`grad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.grad.html) attribute)

For *SGD* it will be something like (*leaving `no_grad` considerations aside*):

```
for param in parameters:
    param -= lr*param.grad
```

---

- ***Backpropagation***

To actually compute the backward propagation you would use [`torch.autograd.backward`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.autograd.backward.html) which usually comes in the form of `torch.Tensor.backward` (as a `torch.Tensor` method).

This function is a mutable operator which will update the `grad` attribute of all *leaf tensor nodes requiring gradient computation*. In other words, it will compute the gradient of the tensor `backward` that was called upon w.r.t each parameter of the model.

For example with model `mlp`, we backpropagate on a dummy loss:

```
>>> for x in mlp.parameters():
...     print(tuple(x.shape), x.grad)
(2, 10) None
(2,)    None
(1, 2)  None
(1,)    None
```

After inference and backpropagation on a random input:

```
>>> mlp(torch.rand(1, 10)).mean().backward()
```

Each `grad` attribute of the model's tensor parameter has been updated by that call:

```
>>> for x in mlp.parameters():
...    print(tuple(x.shape), x.grad is not None, tuple(x.grad.shape))
(2, 10) True (2, 10)
(2,)    True (2,)
(1, 2)  True (1, 2)
(1,)    True (1,)
```

Then you can call `optimizer.step()` to effectively perform the parameter update based on those gradients. Do note, the optimizer can only affect tensors that have been provided to it on initialization (recall the `torch.optim.SGD(mlp.parameters(), lr=1.0e-3)` part).

Finally you can zero the gradient of those parameter from the optimizer directly with [`zero_grad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.Optimizer.zero_grad.html):

```
>>> optimizer.zero_grad()
```

This is roughly a shorthand for:

```
for param in mtl.parameters():
    param.grad.zero_()
```

But its effectiveness is a lot more apparent when using multiple parameters groups and or multiple optimizers on the same model.

Answer (score 2):

The gradient descent algorithm has the learning rate term in it. Since the gradient descent is backpropagated, the learning rate is taken into account during backpropagation.